# Xcode 8.3.2 autocompletion not worked on .m file on a specific project

Tags: ios, xcode, autocomplete, ide, xcode8

Firstly : Xcode autocompletion works on my other project or a newly created project.

I have encountered this problem in only one of my specific project from past 4-5 days. Xcode autocompletion not worked for all my .m (implementation) files. Also it shows all the text in black color except "self", "@implementaion" and "@property" keywords are in correct color. I have tried lots of stuff but can't found anything.

Here is some code :-

```
self.myBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.myBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
self.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
[self addSubview:self.myBackgroundView];

self.myPriceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.myPriceLabel.textColor = [UIColor white];
self.myPriceLabel.font =[MyFiles defaultFontWithSize:12.0];
[self addSubview:self.myPriceLabel];

self.myDiscountLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.myDiscountLabel.font = [MyFiles defaultFontWithSize:12.0];
self.myDiscountLabel.textColor = [UIColor black];
[self addSubview:self.discountLabel];
```

Comment: share some code .

Comment: @kkRocks I have shared code. But I couldn't understand how it is related to  problem.